# Cloudbuild start firebase emulator then npm test

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, firebase-tools

I have a setup that works locally. I can start the emulators, load data in firestore and then run npm test.

I am not sure how to do this on cloudbuild. Here's what I have so far:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  id: MOVE-DOTENV-APP-YAML
  entrypoint: bash
  args:
    - '-e'
    - '-c'
    - |
      cp functions/util/config_dev.js functions/util/config.js
      cp functions/.env_dev functions/.env
- name: node
  dir: 'functions'
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']
- name: 'gcr.io/xxxx/firebase'
  args: ['emulators:start', '--only', 'functions,firestore', '&']
- name: node
  dir: 'functions'
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['test']
```

What I want to add:

```
firebase emulators:start --only functions,firestore &
echo "Waiting for emulator to load..."
while [ $(curl http://localhost:5001/xxx/us-central1/api --silent | grep "Unauthorized" | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; do sleep 2; done
node import-db.js
```

Any ideas on how this can be achieved? I also tried building a firebase image (https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase), but it fails in the cloudbuild.yaml.

The test fails at the emulator start with the following output (    emulators:start --only functions,firestore & ) (but no error that can tell me what is happening)

```
Pulling image: gcr.io/xxxx/firebase
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from xxxx/firebase
8f04e8168e38: Already exists
82e5f66f5d0e: Already exists
c1c8f1c77d66: Already exists
5095cab27771: Already exists
ea7fe362a971: Already exists
9000ed6ad541: Already exists
79733a3c6015: Already exists
10da8f37aebc: Already exists
4641fca333ab: Already exists
f8eea1f9fdb1: Pulling fs layer
38ab87a43f87: Pulling fs layer
38ab87a43f87: Verifying Checksum
38ab87a43f87: Download complete
f8eea1f9fdb1: Verifying Checksum
f8eea1f9fdb1: Download complete
f8eea1f9fdb1: Pull complete
38ab87a43f87: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:c73a50f73c2e19952f1d64228de99ad6c26748f6242393c420b1bfee274e2832
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/xxxx/firebase:latest
gcr.io/xxxx/firebase:latest
```

Comment: You have mentioned that 'it fails in cloudbuild.yaml', does this mean you are getting any errors? If yes, can you please edit the question and mention the error you are getting?

Comment: I just added the part that it fails. No error is produced however the build fails on that step.

Comment: Can you tell where and how you are using the `firebase emulators:start --only functions,firestore` command? Are you using inside the Cloudbuild.yaml file or somewhere else?

Comment: I just updated the code that includes the emulators. I put inside the yaml file

Answer (score 1):

Please note that Firebase Emulator Suite has two requirements:

- Node.js version 8.0 or higher.
- Java version 1.8 or higher.

By looking in the [Firebase Builder Tool](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/blob/master/firebase/Dockerfile), the image is built using Node runtime. Trying to run Firebase Emulator Suite using the Firebase Builder Tool will result to an error due to the missing requirement.

My suggestion is to build your own custom builder or use the following solutions built by the community in this [repository](https://github.com/akauppi/firebase-ci-builder) or the workaround here on the [open issue tracker](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/issues/441). Afterwards, you should be able to run Firebase Emulator via Cloud Build.